# Default parameter value not working correctly in Python's __init__?

Tags: python, initialization, arguments, default

Suppose the following example:

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, data=[]):
        self.data = data
```

If the `data` argument is not given, the instance variable shall be initialized to the default value - an empty list. But consider the following session:

```
>>> e = Example()
>>> print(e.data)
[]
>>> e.data.append(1)
>>> print(e.data)
[1]
>>> e = Example()
>>> print(e.data)
[1]
```

First, an `Example` instance is created without specifying the exact argument value, and thus the default is used. That's expected.

Then, the member variable is modified, and its state changes as expected.

Finally, a new instance of `Example` is created again, the same way as in the first case. Yet, the contents of the member variable are different - the value of the variable somehow "survived" the creation of a new instance. Why?

Is this the expected behavior? What am I doing wrong?

This particular session was done in Python 2.7, but it works the same in Python 3.3.

Thanks, Petr

Comment: [this post](http://www.lexev.org/en/2013/python-mutable-default-arguments/) maybe helpfull

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the explanation, I did not know what I should have looked for before writing this question. After reading the answers, however, I must confess this is the first thing where Python disappointed me. :-(